# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python

```
articles = [t.replace('\n', ' ') for t in articles]
```

Пытаюсь заменить enter на пробел такой строкой. Выводит ошибку:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'.
```

`articles`  - это список, там 200 текстов из xml файла.
Помогите, пожалуйста. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо

Comment: Очевидно некоторые из элементов -- None, добавьте условие `if t`

Comment: @PavelDurmanov, более надёжно всё-таки if t is not None. Конечно, в данном случае это вряд ли на что-то повлияет - если речь об xml файлах, то вряд ли среди них будут пустые строковые значения, которые нужно оставить. Но вообще, нужно всегда помнить, что if x отсеивает не только None, но и пустые строки, коллекции, 0 и false, что далеко не всегда является желательным поведением.

Answer (score 1):

```
articles = [t.replace('\n', ' ') for t in articles if hasattr(t, 'replace')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
articles = [t.replace('\n', ' ') for t in articles if type(t) is str]
```

когда вы хотите одновременно *удалить все объекты, которые не являются строками* (в том числе и значения `None`), или:

---

```
articles = [t.replace('\n', ' ') if type(t) is str else t for t in articles]
```

когда вы хотите *сохранить все элементы* и только для строк применить метод `.replace()`.